# KeyListener not working (requestFocus not fixing it)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener

I am trying to make my first game without the help a youtube video. I have watched many youtube series about making java games and they never where what I wanted to do, so after learning enough I started making my own game. I know enough Java to get around and so far everything has worked with no issues.

I have tried searching for some help but all I could find where people saying the try something along the lines of:

```
setFocusable(true);
requestFocus();
```

This however has not worked for me. I know that most people would not like to just look through all my code but I think it will be manageable (Its not that much code yet).

I plan on making it a sort of snake like game where you get bigger instead of longer and you are a guinea pig (represented by the orange rectangle for now) instead of a snake.

Game.java:

```
package com.kaperly.game;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static JFrame frame;
    public static JPanel panel;

    public static int width = 1000;
    public static int height = 600;

    public Game() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new Panel();

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Guinea Pig Eat");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        panel.setFocusable(true);
        panel.requestFocus(true);

        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
    }

    public static void init() {

    }

    public static void loop() throws InterruptedException { while(true) {
        Character.move();

        Thread.sleep(10);
    }}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        Game game = new Game();

        init();
        loop();
    }
}
```

Panel.java:

```
package com.kaperly.game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static Image startButton;

    public static boolean goingRight = false;
    public static boolean goingLeft = false;
    public static boolean goingUp = false;
    public static boolean goingDown = false;

    private static int changeDirection = 0;

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            goingUp = true;
            changeDirection = 1;
            System.out.println("Moved Up!");

        }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            goingLeft = true;
            changeDirection = 2;

        }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            goingDown = true;
            changeDirection = 3;

        }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            goingRight = true;
            changeDirection = 4;

        }else if(changeDirection == (1 | 2 | 3 | 4)) {
            changeDirection = 0;
            if(changeDirection == 1) {
                goingLeft = false;
                goingDown = false;
                goingRight = false;

            }else if(changeDirection == 2) {
                goingUp = false;
                goingDown = false;
                goingRight = false;

            }else if(changeDirection == 3) {
                goingUp = false;
                goingLeft = false;
                goingRight = false;

            }else if(changeDirection == 4) {
                goingUp = false;
                goingLeft = false;
                goingDown = false;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        //Set background color
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, Game.width, Game.height);


        //Make Walls
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, Game.width, 25);
        g.fillRect(0, 550, Game.width, 25);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 25, Game.height);
        g.fillRect(970, 0, 25, Game.height);

        //Show Character
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.fillRect(Character.x, Character.y, Character.width, Character.height);

        repaint();
    }
}
```

Character.java:

```
package com.kaperly.game;

public class Character {

    public static int x = 475;
    public static int y = 250;

    public static int width = 50;
    public static int height = 75;

    public static void move() {
        if(Panel.goingUp == true) {
            y = y ++;
        }
        if(Panel.goingLeft == true) {
            x = x --;
        }
        if(Panel.goingDown == true) {
            y = y --;
        }
        if(Panel.goingRight == true) {
            x = x ++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do always remember, never to make a call to `repaint()` from within method responsible for painting, such as in this case the `paintComponent(...)` method, since in this situation it will be called recursively unnecessarily, which is not a good practice.

Comment: Please have a look at [Motion using Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/), it will tell you the benefit of using `Key Bindings` over `KeyListeners` :-)

Answer (score 3):

`KeyListener` should be avoid BECAUSE of it's inherent focus related issues.  You never know what might take keyboard focus away from your component.

Instead, take advantage of the [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) API, which allows you to control the focus level required to trigger your key events.

It will also allow you to reuse underlying `Action` associated with the key binding in other places...

You'd be wise to rename you class `Panel` to something more meaningful.  AWT already has a `Panel` class and it would be very easy to confuse the two

Comment: I changed the name of "Panel.java" to "Render.java" and I will look into key bindings.

Comment: I have tried doing this and keybinds are not working either. Here is the code now: Game.java: http://pastebin.com/8eLiQWHw Render.java: http://pastebin.com/jyJAKMgv Character.java: http://pastebin.com/iSAc092k Input.java: http://pastebin.com/4XXHZicH

Comment: Did you use JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW when getting the InputMap from your panel

Comment: 1- Don't rely on `static` references (in this context), they will simply blow up in your face. 2- The instance of the panel you are registering your key bindings to is not the same one on the screen, so the bindings will never work. 3- You should consider using `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW` instead of `WHEN_FOCUSED`

Answer (score 2):

`KeyListener` has 2 big issues, they are binded for all keys and besides component must be focusable and in focus, `JPanel` is not focusable by default.

It's strongly dicourage the use of `requestFocus` see the api.

Instead of that you can use [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) where you bind a specific key an action.

You may interested in @camickr blog where he post swing utils things like this [Motion using the keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/).

Also don't call a class `Panel` cause it's JPanel parent class name , it's gives to confusion.

Change this:

```
public class Game extends JFrame {

private JFrame frame;

}
```

to

```
public class Game {

private JFrame frame;
}
```

Another thing don't implement `KeyListener` at top level class, instead of that use `anonymous classes` or `private classes` you are breaking [Single Responsability Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the keylistener on either your game or panel class. The docs have this to say:

> The listener object created from that class is then registered with a component using the component's addKeyListener method. A keyboard event is generated when a key is pressed, released, or typed. The relevant method in the listener object is then invoked, and the KeyEvent is passed to it.

So in Panel you could do the following

```
  public Panel(){
        addKeyListener(this);
    }
```

There are other things wrong with your code but this should have input working.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. Still does not move the rectangle or display "Moved Up!".

Comment: @arynaq - you may want to chain your `Panel` constructor to `super()`