# KeyListener Not working/Not being called?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jlabel, keylistener

I'm making a small program to test out a `KeyListener`, making the main class, and only class, implement it. I started by making a class within the class, implementing key listener, and adding the line:

```
this.addKeyListener(new Handler());
```

But that didn't work so I made the main class implement key listener, and still the `KeyPressed`/typed/released are not being called.  Ive shortened the class a lot, so here it is:

```
public class Game_Main extends JPanel implements KeyListener{

JLabel ship = new JLabel();
JLabel bg = new JLabel();

static JFrame frame;

public Game_Main(){
    setPreferredSize(size);

    this.addKeyListener(this);


}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Game_Main g = new Game_Main();
    frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setPreferredSize(size);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(g);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("ds");
    }

}
```

Comment: Try defining which key is types using the KeyEvent in required method.

Comment: 1) For Swing, typically use key bindings over the AWT based, lower level, `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details on how to use them.  2) A `JPanel` is typically not focusable to key events.

Comment: possible duplicate of [KeyListener not working (requestFocus not fixing it)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029136/keylistener-not-working-requestfocus-not-fixing-it)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  An SSCCE of a run-time problem should compile & run, whereas what is posted does not compile even after imports are added.

Comment: Fixed the error, thanks Hovercraft for that. All i needed to do was add a setFocusable(true); because by default JPanel has it set to false or something like that.

Comment: *"Fixed the error,"*  Now either answer the question or delete it..

Comment: Im sorry, i cant answer the question for a few hours it says, so i thought i might just post the answer in a comment until i can answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution for this problem would be to make an instance in the main method for example:

```
KeyListener() listener = new Game_Main();
```

Then you can cut the line:

```
this.addKeyListener(this);
```

from the constructor and put it in the main method. After than change the first this to frame and the second this to listener, it will work just fine. You simply register or input the listener to the frame in order to execute the event.